# How do I differentiate a group reference from a number that follows it?

Tags: python, regex

I'm attempting to replace all occurances of a particular number within a string. For example, lets say I want to replace specific instances of a given number with another:

```
>>> number1 = 33
>>> number2 = 1
>>> re.sub('(foo)%i' % number1, '\\1%i' % number2, 'foo33')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
  File "/home/david_clymer/Development/VistaShare/ot_git/lib/python2.4/sre.py", line 142, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, 0).sub(repl, string, count)
  File "/home/david_clymer/Development/VistaShare/ot_git/lib/python2.4/sre.py", line 260, in filter
    return sre_parse.expand_template(template, match)
  File "/home/david_clymer/Development/VistaShare/ot_git/lib/python2.4/sre_parse.py", line 784, in expand_template
    raise error, "invalid group reference"
sre_constants.error: invalid group reference
>>> re.sub('(foo)%i' % number1, '\\1 %i' % number2, 'foo33')
'foo 1'
```

How can I keep the group reference from being conflated with the following number?

Comment: This was asked a while ago on here. Let me find that question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import re

number1 = 33
number2 = 1
print re.sub('(foo)%i' % number1, '\g<1>%i' % number2, 'foo33')
```

> `re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)`
>
> In addition to character escapes and backreferences as described
>   above, `\g<name>` will use the substring matched by the group named
>   name, as defined by the `(?P<name>...)` syntax. `\g<number>` uses the
>   corresponding group number; `\g<2>` is therefore equivalent to `\2`, but
>   isn’t ambiguous in a replacement such as `\g<2>0`. `\20` would be
>   interpreted as a reference to group 20, not a reference to group 2
>   followed by the literal character '0'. The backreference `\g<0>`
>   substitutes in the entire substring matched by the RE.
>
> http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-re

Answer (score 1):

Apparently named groups can be referenced using `\g<name>`:

```
>>> re.sub('(?P<prefix>foo)%i' % number1, '\\g<prefix>%i' % number2, 'foo33')
'foo1'
```

The python docs for `re.sub()` actually explain this. Go figure: http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: Might wish to consider r'\g<prefix>`... instead to escape the string literal

Comment: @JonClements: I'm doing that...but the bracketed values are getting munged on display, apparently.

Comment: I think Jon's talking about using Python's raw string notation so you don't have to double the backslashes: `r'\g<prefix>'` as opposed to `'\\g<prefix>'`.  Also, you can use the named-group syntax with numbered groups, as @eyquem demonstrated.